# How to make a discord bot that gives roles in Python?

Tags: python, bots, roles, discord, discord.py

I want to create a discord bot that gives roles to members in Python.

I tried this:

```
@async def on_message(message):
     if message.content == "give me admin"
           role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Admin")
           await client.add_roles(message.author.id, role)
```

Comment: The bot has Administrator permissions!

Comment: The `@` in front of `async` shouldn't be there.  This function should be decorated with `@client.event`, or something similar.  Instead of `message.author.id`, just pass `message.author` to `add_roles`

Comment: The program returned: "NameError: name 'server' is not defined"

Comment: Use `message.server.roles`.

Comment: Ok i will try. Thx!

Comment: Pls stay here if this doesn't working

Comment: NameError: name 'name' is not defined(from name="admin")

Comment: Could you copy/paste that line directly here?  `name='Admin'` should work like you expect it to, so I suspect there's a syntax error somewhere that's causing the problem

Comment: I resolved the NameError: name 'name' is not defined(from name="admin") but I have a new problem: TypeError: find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Comment: That's because [`find`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.find) doesn't take keyword arguments, it takes a predicate function. Are you using `find` or `get`?

Comment: I'm using find!

Comment: Should I use get?

Comment: You can use either, they both do pretty much the same thing. `find(lambda x: x.name == 'Admin', message.server.roles)` and `get(message.server.role, name='Admin')` should get the same result.  I tend to prefer `get`, but you can use either.

Comment: Can you give me a full code! Please?

Comment: OK!Be right back!

Answer (score 7):

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'give me admin':
        role = get(message.server.roles, name='Admin')
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
```

I think this should work.  The documentation for [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) is [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#).

You could also use the `discord.ext.commands` extension:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import discord

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def addrole(ctx, role: discord.Role, member: discord.Member=None):
    member = member or ctx.message.author
    await client.add_roles(member, role)

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: Thank You! You helped me very much!

Comment: Using this code I get this error: "new_roles = utils._unique(role.id for role in itertools.chain(member.roles, roles))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'"

Comment: @MikeyJY Then there's no role on your server named `Admin`

Comment: I know what is the problem: The role is named: Admin+an emoji but I use Python IDLE and when I put emoji the file is closing. Can I use role id?

Comment: Yes.  change `role = get(message.server.roles, name='Admin')` to `role = get(message.server.roles, id='<role id>')`

Comment: Ok I'll try this!

Comment: But how to get id of a role. Isn't "\@role"?

Comment: Yes.  Some roles can't be mentioned though, so you would have to change that setting in the server settings

Comment: Can I get the id of the admin using the bot?

Comment: Are there any other roles named `Admin<something>`?  If not, we could use `find(lambda x: x.startswith('Admin'), message.server.roles)`

Comment: I have one more question for you.

Comment: Hi Patrick, may I enlist your help with an issue i have regarding this? In  my code I have, is a bit different to this. In my code I already know the discord if for a user, and i get the role using `ctx.guild.roles` when i try using client.add_roles(), i get an error saying bot has no attribute 'add_roles()'

Comment: @KebabProgrammer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052536/attributeerror-bot-object-has-no-attribute-add-roles

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "give me admin":
        member = message.author
        role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Admin")
        await member.add_roles(role)
```