# AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing a bot for discord in Python. I want that when someone logged in to the server, he was given a certain role

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
from discord.utils import get

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = get(member.roles, name="Игроки")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)
```

When I start and someone enters the server, I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you're using the [latest version of the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).  You should be getting the role from the guild and using [`Member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Игроки")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Now I get the following error: discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 FORBIDDEN (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

Comment: Either your bot lacks the `manage_roles` permission, or you are trying to add a role that is higher in the role hierarchy than your bots highest role.