# Make a discord bot with Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('bot, '):
        if message.content[5:].startswith(('clear')):
            if message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
                amount=int(message.content[10:])
                await message.channel.purge(limit=amount)
            else:
                await message.channel.send('not enough energy.')
```

In addition to administrators,
I would like to have certain roles perform commands.
What should I do?

role name = not admin
id = 825183755484266529

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please explain your code, errors you face and what you want to know. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a discord bot that gives roles in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987006/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-that-gives-roles-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can get `message.author.roles`, which is a `list` of `Role`s. You can then iterate this list and check if any of the roles have the "admin" role id. Example:

```py
ADMIN_ROLE_ID = 1234567890
def can_perform_commands(member):
    for role in member.roles:
        if role.id == ADMIN_ROLE_ID:
            return True
    return False
```

You can then use this function like this:

```py
if can_perform_commands(message.author):
    # do whatever the command does
else:
    message.channel.send("I'm sorry, but you don't have permission to use this command.")
```

Comment: sorry i don`t understand

Comment: `message.author.roles` is a list. It contains the roles of the message author. The first piece of code defines a function which looks through this list and checks if any of the role IDs are the same as the admin role's ID. If there is one - which means the user has the admin role - it returns True. In other cases, it returns False. The second code calls this function and passes the message author to it. If it returns True, it goes on and does what the command does normally. Else, it sends a message about the user not having enough permissions.